# jpackage (Java 15) installer throws "vcruntime150.dll missing" on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, wix, jpackage

I want to ship my javafx application with an easy installer.
Since Java 15, jpackage ommits the dlls inside the main folder. Windows 7 doesn't have vcruntime140.dll builtin, so at starts it throws "Program couldn't be started because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing...", but starts anyway when pressing "OK".

As installing VC redist 2015-2019 requires admin privileges, I want to include the missing dlls to the InstallDir instead, by setting the overrides.wxi as mentioned in
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6.

But I don't have a clue what to write in this file.